# Robot Meta tag and Robots.txt both are Different?

Tags: header-files, software-design

anyone can suggest me how to use  Robot meta tag. Robots meta tag is beneficial for SEO Or Robots.txt file. I cant understand please clear me. should i use  in our website header tag or not. I want to index all web page on search engine. what should i do for IT.

Answer (score 0):

A robots.txt file allows you to allow or deny access to your whole website for different robots and crawlers from one simple file in the root of your public web folder.

> Web site owners use the /robots.txt file to give instructions about
>   their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion
>   Protocol.

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

The robots meta tags allow you to control things at a more granular level, page by page, and also whether a page is indexed, whether the links on a page should be followed and so on.

> You can use a special HTML  tag to tell robots not to index the
>   content of a page, and/or not scan it for links to follow.

http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

You don't *need* to use either for SEO purposes but either or both can be useful for keeping parts of your site "private" or helping search engine crawlers to understand which parts of your website are important. There is more information about this here: https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt